# Можно ли создать приложение для iOS и Android из сайта

Tags: android, ios

Идея такая: создать сайт-приложение и его обернуть в приложение для ios/android.

Можно ли так сделать, и чтобы ещё приняли в appstore и playmarket?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Так же есть такое решение как ionic. Ознакомится можно тут https://ionicframework.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то да, можно. Для этого можно использовать apache cordova. Этот фрэймворк позволяет создавать мобильные приложения используя HTML5,Css, JavaScript. Больше информации тут:
https://cordova.apache.org/

Вот пример работы с данным фрэймворком:
http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

Comment: большое спасибо, а при этом позволят ли appstore и playmarket добавить такое приложение. Дело в том, что один из  сайтов - сложная система, даже если писать отдельно под гостевую часть полноценное приложение, его нужно будет обслуживать и очень непросто, т.к. часто бывают какие-то доработки или нововведения

Comment: и еще вопрос, сайт у меня не статический, как в этом случае поступить

Comment: Да, такие приложения могут быть загружены в маркет, как любые другие.
Обновляться такое приложение так же будет стандартными методами, как любое другое. на выходе вы получите обычное андройд приложение. Оно не будет отличаться от других!

Comment: а ajax ведь нельзя на другой сервер отправлять, как быть, как мне передать данные другому серверу?

Comment: затупил, это же политика браузеров, так что нам не помеха. Пользуюсь Вашим способом и очень благодарен, как закончу напишу статейку для хабра)

Answer (score 2):

Создать пустое приложение, загрузить в нем UIWebView/WebView и открыть нужный сайт

Comment: большое спасибо, а при этом позволят ли appstore и playmarket добавить такое приложение. Дело в том, что один из  сайтов - сложная система, даже если писать отдельно под гостевую часть полноценное приложение, его нужно будет обслуживать и очень непросто, т.к. часто бывают какие-то доработки или нововведения

Comment: Не скажу насчет android, а у apple в их interface guidelines прямо сказано, что делать так нельзя. Я бы сказал, что они правы - если у вас просто вэб сайт, не надо его пытаться сделать приложением.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое решение как ionic -  популярный фреймвёрк для оборачивания web-приложения на Ангуляре в нативное с возможностью прокинуть прокинуть туда некоторые возможности нативных приложений.

Ознакомится можно тут https://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120738/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-aleksandr-barakin).